# How can I call an Oracle function from Delphi?

Tags: oracle, delphi, function

I created a function in Oracle that inserts records in specific tables and return an output according to what occurs within the function. e.g (ins_rec return number)

How do I call this function and see its output in Delphi?

I got a reply (with all my thanks) for sql plus but I need to know how can I do this in Delphi

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  You can show your thanks to people who have answered questions by marking an answer as correct.  Click the green tick by the answer.  Afraid I can't help you with this question though - I know nothing about Delphi.  :)

Answer (score 7):

Just pass the user defined function as column name in the query and it will work.

Example:

```
Var
  RetValue: Integer;
begin
  Query1.Clear;
  Query1.Sql.Text := 'Select MyFunction(Param1) FunRetValue from dual';
  Query1.Open;

  if not Query1.Eof then
  begin
    RetValue := Query1.FieldByName('FunRetValue').AsInteger;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oracle has the DUAL special table to be used when you need something like this. Your code may not perform what you expect - it can call the function *for each row* of <YourTable>.

Answer (score 6):

How to accomplish it may depend on what DB access library you use (BDE? dbExpress? ADO? others), some may offer a "stored procedure" component that may work with functions as well.

A general approach it to use an anonymous PL/SQL block to call the function (and a parameter to read the return value), PL/SQL resembles Pascal a lot...:

```
Qry.SQL.Clear;
Qry.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
Qry.SQL.Add('  :Rez := ins_rec;');
Qry.SQL.Add('END;');
// Set the parameter type here...
...
Qry.ExecSQL;
...
ReturnValue :=  Qry.ParamByName('Rez').Value;
```

I would not have used a function, though, but a stored procedure with an OUT value. Moreover, Oracle offers *packages* that are a very nice way to organize procedure and functions, and they also offer useful features like session variables and initialization/finalization sections...  very much alike a Delphi unit.

Answer (score 0):

we run an Oracle stored procedure using this code that utilizes the BDE (I know please don't bash because we used the BDE!)

```
Try
  DMod.Database1.Connected:= False;
  DMod.Database1.Connected:= True;
  with DMod.StoredProc1 do
  begin
    Active:= False;

    ParamByName('V_CASE_IN').AsString:= Trim(strCaseNum);
    ParamByName('V_WARRANT_IN').AsString:= strWarrantNum;
    ParamByName('V_METRO_COMMENTS').AsString:= strComment;

    Prepare;
    ExecProc;

    Result:= ParamByName('Result').AsString;
  end;
Except
```